# Why url X dont match regex, gae webapp2 related

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

Why this

```
/download/vzC43Wji33B21DRJYSoYFQ%3D%3D
```

do not match this

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),
                           ('/upload', UploadHandler),
                           ('/download/<resource:>', DownloadHandler)],
                          debug=True)
```

I am getting a 404 error and DownloadHandler is not executed at all.

Comment: my guess is whatever %3D is is not an allowed url character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a simple route with an URL template. To use a URL template you have to use the webapp2.Route class. See this doc: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#extended-routes